# How do I turn off timezone adjustments for springboot 3?

Tags: java, spring-boot, date, jackson, timezone

Ive been going through many different post about this issue but seem unable to make any proposed solution work. I have added this:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE =false
```

To my applications.properties file but this doesn't work. I tried implementing a custom deserializer but that doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how to get spring to read the time fields straight fcrom the db without adjusting the timezone for each value?

EDIT: I have tried a new method and I actually changed the offset being applied to the output records. In my STarterApp class I added this:

```
    @PostConstruct
    void started() {
        TimeZone.setDefault(null);
        //TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }
```

The null only applies an hour to each record where as using UTC applies about 5 hours. Is their a way I can set timezone to have spring not adjust the times returned to include timezone differences? I just want the time that was saved originally without the offset

Comment: Which Java object are you using as representation for your timestamp? There are timestamp objects without timezone information, e.g. ‘java.sql.Timestamp‘ or ‘LocalDateTime‘.

Comment: Are you asking what variable I set my objects to? If so in each entity they are setup like this:

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)
 @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
 private Date expectedArrivalTime;

Comment: In an entity I would prefer ja.sql.Timestamp instead of java.util.Date... However, in what format is your timstamp transferred? Did you output the json? I thought that Jackson just converts timestamps to a huge milliseconds number.

Comment: The latest formal version of Spring Boot is `2.2.2`, what did you mean `springboot 3`?